# sign_up hook with Devise and Apartment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, multi-tenant

I have `gem devise` and `gem apartment` which I want to use to create separate schema for each user. I'm looking for a good way to call `Apartment::Database.create(current_user)` when user sign_up.

I found this at devise's registrations_controller.rb:

```
# Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own
# RegistrationsController.
def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
end
```

but I'm not sure how it should be done.
I suppose it can be something similar to this at application_controller.rb:

```
def sign_up(user)    
  super user
  Apartment::Database.create(current_user.username)
end
```

I wrote this looking at [this sign_in override example](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/issues/424) but I have some concerns:

1. about `user` argument as super function uses different parameters (`resource_name, resource`).
2. I wish to call `Apartment::Database.create` only if user signed up successfully.
3. I'm not sure but I think `user` can be used here instead of `current_user` method (assuming it's used to sign up new user).
4. What about putting the create call at User model as `after_create` hook ? Is it a good idea ?

that way at `model/User.rb`

```
  after_create :create_schema

  private

  def create_schema    
    Apartment::Database.create(self.username)
  end
```

**Above code seams to work fine but I'm not sure if it's a proper way and I would like to ask you to comment override concerns even if it is.**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think it is rightly placed in the model. If you're using `confirmable` with `devise` you might want to update your hook to `after confirm` (unsure of exact implementation). Keep your controllers simple.